# How to conditionally map/ignore properties based on user role in AutoMapper in asp.net core

Tags: c#, automapper

I'm using `AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection 7.0.0`

I need to map properties only for user with specific roles else ignore the mapping using automapper in my asp.net core 3.0 project.

Here is what I tried,

```cs
public class BranchProfile : Profile
{
    private readonly HttpContext _httpContext;

    public BranchProfile(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        _httpContext = httpContextAccessor.HttpContext;

        CreateMap<Branch, BranchEditViewModel>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Lock, opt => opt.Condition(src => _httpContext.User.IsInRole(UserRoles.Master.ToString())))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.ExpireOn, opt => opt.Condition(src => _httpContext.User.IsInRole(UserRoles.Master.ToString())));
    }
}
```

But I get the following no parameter less constructor exception.

> No parameterless constructor defined for type 'BranchProfile'

Any better way to access `HttpContext` to do this conditional mapping? Please assist

Comment: AutoMapper supports DI in Custom Value Resolvers, Custom Type Converters, and Value Converters. You need a resolver here.

Comment: I tried to write custom resolver but in my case I need to ignore mapping if user is not in specific role. How to ignore mapping or map using resolver? I couldn't find a proper example in docs. How to inject `IHttpContextAccessor` in custom resolver? please assist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I achieved the functionality using `IMappingAction`. `IMappingAction` supports DI and I injected `IHttpContextAccessor` and used `AfterMap` to map/reject(reset to original values) mappings based on user role.

**Mapping Profile:**

```cs
public class BranchProfile : Profile
{
    public BranchProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<Branch, BranchEditViewModel>()
            .AfterMap<MapOnlyForMasterUserAction>();;
    }
}
```

**IMappingAction:**

```cs
public class MapOnlyForMasterUserAction : IMappingAction<BranchEditViewModel, Branch>
{
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

    public MapOnlyForMasterUserAction(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(httpContextAccessor));
    }

    public void Process(BranchEditViewModel source, Branch destination, ResolutionContext context)
    {
        if (_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.IsInRole(IdentityEnums.UserRoles.Master.ToString()))
        {
            destination.Lock = source.Lock.ToString();
            destination.ExpireOn = source.ExpireOn.ToShortDateString();
        }
        else 
        {
            destination.Lock = destination.Lock;
            destination.ExpireOn = destination.ExpireOn;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect answer, thank you !

Comment: Glad it helped you. you're welcome.